# Creating an array of integers from argv in C

Tags: c, arrays, argv, cs50

its going to be quite obvious I am brand new to this but I am taking the CS50 course and I'm having a hard time with one of my assignments. I thought this would be simple but there is something flawed in my syntax causing runtime errors.
I am trying to create an array using each character from a command line argument as elements for the array but nothing I try seems to work. Here's the chunk that's tripping me up:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //make sure only 2 command line arguments entered
    if( argc != 2)
        {
        printf("Please input a keyword composing of letters only\n");
        return 1;
        }
     else
     {
         // declare variable "m" to designate the number of elements in the array "keyword"
        int m = strlen(argv[1]);
        //array declaration for "keyword" with "m" elements
        int keyword[m];
        //convert characters to integers
        keyword[m] = atoi(argv[1]);
        //iterate through characters in argv[1] in order to printf the elements in the array
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[1]); j++)
        printf("%i",keyword[j]);
     }
}
```

So, I know this is really really wrong but can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){ if(isupper((unsigned char)argv[1][i]) keyword[i] = argv[1][i] - 'A'; else if(islower((unsigned char)argv[1][i]) keyword[i] = argv[1][i] - 'a'; else { printf("invalid character %c included.\n", argv[1][i]); return 1; } }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i correctly understood what you want to do, but if you only want to extract from a number given in parameter of your program each figure composing it you can do it like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //make sure only 2 command line arguments entered
    if( argc != 2)
        {
        printf("Please input a keyword composing of letters only\n");
        return 1;
        }
     else
     {
         // declare variable "m" to designate the number of elements in the array "keyword"
        int m = strlen(argv[1]);
        //array declaration for "keyword" with "m" elements
        int keyword[m];
        //convert characters to integers
        //iterate through characters in argv[1] in order to printf the elements in the array
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[1]); j++){
          keyword[j] = argv[1][j] - '0';
          printf("%d\n",keyword[j]);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like 48.  Instead of 48, you could use `'0'`.